# How can I describe an FSA where one or more inputs generate outputs but do not cause transitions?

Tags: finite-automata

I have been asked to describe through an FSA a system where some inputs do not determine any state transitions, but that provide outputs. There is no self-transition, and the input is not rejected: the state literally does not change, while an output is produced. I started with NFSAs, but it does not seem to suit the requirements.
Is there any way to describe and represent this situation?

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "do not determine any state transitions" and "no self-transition".  An input that does not cause any change to the state is called a self-transition.  Can you state the requirements more precisely?  Perhaps give a motivating example and a mathematical problem specification?